# Android/kotlin how to resume execution after having to stop to ask for permission

Tags: broadcastreceiver

So, in Android/Kotlin suppose that you want to do something that needs a permission such as to list Bluetooth devices.

There seem to be two ways of doing it, one with a `BroadcastReceiver`, and another with `override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)`

- How do you choose which?

Although it seems that some situations only support one or the other. For example it appears that requesting permission to a USB device *must* be done with a `BroadcastReceiver`.

- Is this true?

The `BroadcastReceiver` thing seems to go something like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var usbManager:UsbManager
    private lateinit var usbDevice:UsbDevice

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 
        usbManager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
        getUsbDevice()

        if(!usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice))
        {
           // Now we have to abandon our attempt to start up and go ask for permission.
           // But how do we resume starting up after permission has been granted?
            val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0)
            val filter = IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)
            registerReceiver(usbDevicePermissionReceiver, filter)
            usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, permissionIntent)

            // should we return here and then we don't have to else?
            // Do we need to prevent onResume from running before we have permission?
        } else {
            // All good; continue starting up.
            startWorker()
        }
}

// Why is this code not inside a class? 
private const val ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "some_made_up_string"

private val usbDevicePermissionReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == intent.action) {
            synchronized(this) {
                val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    startWorker() // This method of MainActivity doesn't exist in this context.
                } else {
                    Log.d("com.rwb.doodah", "permission denied for device $device")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(1) What are the parameters `context` and `intent`? I would guess that `intent` is the one that I created in `onCreate`?

(2) What is a conext?

(3) Why is the `ACTION_USB_PERMISSION` and the `usbDevicePermissionReceiver`  outside of a class? I have a C# background so this seems like complete nonsense.

(4) What is `synchronized(this)`?

And, finally, my main question is:
(5) How do you resume execution when the permission has been granted (or terminate if it hasn't). I.e., how is control passed back to me in my `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

This feels very wrong.

```
private class UsbDevicePermissionReceiver(val activity:MainActivity) : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == intent.action) {
            synchronized(this) {
                val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                // ^^ Not a

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    activity.startWorker()
                } else {
                    Log.d("RWB", "permission denied for device $device")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and to call it:

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        if(!usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice))
        {
            val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0)
            val filter = IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)
            val br = UsbDevicePermissionReceiver(this)
            registerReceiver(br, filter)
            usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, permissionIntent)
        }
        else {
            startWorker()
        }
    }
```